# Sitecore Powershell Extensions - Reports Authorization

Tags: security, powershell-extensions

I've created some PSE scripts to give our client some reports on their content. I created them under the proper convention of Script Module and Script Library so that the reports show up under Reporting Tools in the Sitecore start menu.

Tree:

[image: tree]

Menu:

[image: menu]

This works great for an admin. What I can't figure out is how to grant access to these reports to editors. In Core, I've given Read access to /sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Right/Reporting Tools/PowerShell Reports. I've also given read access in Master to my script module, script library and individual scripts.

What am I missing to allow editors to see these reports in the Sitecore start menu? With the access changes noted above, they only see an empty Powershell Reports menu.

Comment: did you try Ribbon -->Security --> Assign options @ Master DB for these reports.

Comment: Are you running v4.3 of PSE? There was a lot of work on security in that version and there is a known issue with a misspelled role name in the default configuration:
https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/765

In short, check the App_Config/Include/Cognifide.PowerShell.config file for the incorrect "sitecore\Sitecore Client User" role and change it to "sitecore\Sitecore Client Users". 

Since the issue is fixed on github, I assume that the next release will be correct so it should be safe to update the config file directly instead of patching in a separate file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Security Setup

Here are the steps I followed to grant access.

1. Navigate to the item `/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Right/Reporting Tools/PowerShell Reports`
2. Grant access to `sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring`

[image: Security Change]

3. See changes.

[image: Report now available]

---

#### Troubleshooting

[image: Execution Missing]

If you see the report menu item but does not expand, ensure that the user has access to the group defined in the configuration for [*Execution*](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/security.html) service.

**Example:** If you decided to use a different group in the above, then be sure to patch the setting below. [Issue #765](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/765) will be addressed in 4.4, however you can manually fix it.

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <powershell>
      <services>
        <remoting>
          <authorization>
            <patch:delete />
          </authorization>
          <authorization>
            <add Permission="Allow" IdentityType="Role" Identity="sitecore\Sitecore Client Users" />
          </authorization>
        </remoting>
      </services>
    </powershell>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

---

#### Book Documentation

Instructions from this page have been copied to the [book](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/reports.html).